# Flutter: VS Code doesn't highlight compile time errors in test files

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

I have unit tests in my Flutter project. The problem is VS Code doesn't highlight compilation errors in test files as it does in all other dart files. It just prints errors to debug console.

This is how compilation error looks like in plain dart code file:

[image]

This is how compilation error looks like in test file:

[image]

Here is my test tab after tests run, `chart_bloc_test.dart` contains compilation errors:

[image]

Flutter version: `Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.0, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2, locale ru-RU)`.

VS Code version: `Version: 1.50.0`

**Question:**

What should I do to make compile time errors be highlighted in test files? Is it VS Code or Flutter or Dart bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved. It is because of my  analysis_options.yaml excluded `/test` folder...

Answer (score 0):

Do your tests live in the test directory under the project root and do they end in _test.dart?

Comment: As you can see in test tab screenshot, yes they do

Comment: You can try running pub upgrade a couple of times and restarting vscode (which I've assume you have done by now). There is a bug in vs code where it doesn't always notice a pub upgrade/pub updates and you have take the actions noted above.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help(
Tried to reinstall Flutter and Dart extensions - no results too.

Comment: Try a little experiment. In vs-code go to the implementation class (i.e. not the test class). Open the vs-code tool launcher (can't remember what it is called but I use ctrl-shift-p on linux) select the option Dart: Goto to test/implementation file. If the test file doesn't exist vs code will offer to create it. Create the file and then see if it compiles. The theory I'm working on is that the test library is in the wrong directory.

Comment: Nice option, I didn't know about it.  The launcher called command palette.

Comment: As you say, I created test from the command palette. This test compiles like everyone else - without highlighted compilation errors in code.
I think the test directory is correct. Compiler works fine with test files and prints out all errors to the debug console. The problem is it doesn't highlight errors in code.